# Is there any security vulnerability in this code?

Tags: security

It goes like this:

```
exec("echo '" + param + "' > /etc/test")
```

And note that it's under root privilege and param has filtered characters like:

```
'
"
;
`
&
```

Comment: Yes. For one thing, you must be root to run that program (since it writes to /etc). For another, how can you guarantee `param` doesn't contain those characters?

Comment: You might want to tell us, what programming language this is.

Comment: @eckes I don't think it has anything to do with programming languages. :)

Comment: Sure it has, string concatenation might be unsafe, exec might have safer variants, do (no) escaping. etc. It is not even clear who would interpret the output redirection (shell?).

Comment: Yes, it is unsafe; you are running it as root.  Without a lot more information, it is not possible to say whether it might be safer than it appears at first sight, but in the absence of any other information, it will be unsafe.

Comment: a pipe `|` in `param` might cause trouble

Comment: @codesinchaos Note that the pipe `|` doesn't work within quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will not get a yes/no answer without much more context. That's okay; instead let us look for weaknesses and highlight areas for concern.

Issue 1: it is almost always better to avoid passing untrusted/externally-supplied data into a shell command; the shell provides a dangerous level of power if someone manages to subvert your command with bad input. Open and write the file in your own code rather than using a shell to do it.

Issue 2: it's impossible to say if that exec() would be safe without knowing what shell the command line will be evaluated by.

Issue 3: if you must pass data via a shell (but see Issue 1), robust filtering is vital. But from your brief description of the filtering, it sounds like you are blacklisting known-bad characters - this is a poor approach, it is always better to whitelist known-good characters and keep that to a very limited set (such alphanumeric).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the PATH, then you cannot be sure what command is executed. You also did not say how you sanitize param. There are a few things to avoid:

- Why do you use exec/echo at all? Any programming language can write to files directly.
- the "single string" exec() method needs to deal with parsing/escaping. If you use a method which uses a string array, you dont need to be concerned with it.
- In your case /etc is a safe dir, but if you use the same code on a less protected directory you might follow a symlink and destroy anything an attacker wants you to
- You should be aware that the content of your newly created file contains blank delimited file names, but filesnames can contain blanks. So malicious attackers can produce new (non existing) names. (In fact all characters (including line breaks) besides \0 can be part of the filename).
- You need to setup a clean (i.e. only add whitelisted entries) environment. LD_PRELOAD, PATH, IFS, CWD/PWD or SHELL, all can be tainted.

Comment: Let's say anything other than this code is guaranteed safe.

Comment: @Badesign: that doesn't help narrow down what might go wrong with this code.  You've not given us enough information to go on yet.